# java web application loading error at server with tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, server, tomcat8

I am using apache tomcat 8.5 and java 8 version in my web application server..

Environment variables : JRE_HOME, CATALINA_HOME are set correctly in server but not JAVA_HOME (jdk)
Is this a issue for my web page not loading error....

Comment: jsp has not loaded properly. From Homepage the page alignments are collapsed

Answer (score 0):

Your versions are not match together.

Download apache tomcat 9 - http://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi or use JDK 7 or later.

GoodLuck!

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Reza, should i match jdk7 with tomcat 8.5, if possible?

Comment: it depends on your needs, use JDK 8 when you need JDK 8 features. if not use JDK 7 with same configured tomcat on your system. also if this answer solved your problem you can mark it as correct. :)

Comment: Thanks ji :) for your valuable comments